# How to update multiple objects off a OneToMany relationship at a time?

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I'm using `ApiPlatform`

Let's say I have an entity `User` with a `OneToMany` on another entity called `Experience`, so my user can have mulitple experiences.

The experiences are already loaded in the db, every user has 100 of them and only is able to precise the duration.

I'm wondering what's the best way to update 10 experiences at a time.

I've tried something like that on postman :

```json
{
    "user": "/users/444217d0-84fa-4800-9c06-6f604f1be23f",
    "experiences": [
        {"@id": "/experiences/7c4f2f38-33cb-4e47-950e-0b5bea4014b4", "duration": 2},
        {"@id": "/experiences/975c09b3-2430-4120-9c9e-f5e37032a5f9", "duration": 2},
        {"@id": "/experiences/d2d8cbd8-e15e-4fc7-8238-55a915d69cd5", "duration": 3},
        {"@id": "/experiences/ec54b2b1-a009-4d47-b14d-b1720d948dd4", "duration": 4},
        {"@id": "/experiences/e734cd66-a328-43ae-9cd7-12bec7dd0615", "duration": 5},
        {"@id": "/experiences/b640ed04-4e43-4844-abd4-2c0453731712", "duration": 4},
        {"@id": "/experiences/1bc84609-c8a6-4b53-9245-bd1458cad716", "duration": 3},
        {"@id": "/experiences/fa426aa3-7792-440c-a5cf-05e2263ce2bc", "duration": 2},
        {"@id": "/experiences/072f4bb9-4b91-4063-a5c7-6d713322c8a4", "duration": 1},
        {"@id": "/experiences/f2e66837-99bb-4c34-9544-ac56c721345b", "duration": 1}
    ]
}
```

It worked but erases the 90 other experiences linked to that user.

Anyone knows a way to update 10 objects of this collection without erasing the 90 others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately sending nested documents is a not very mature feature in Api Platform. As long as you configured the properties of $user accordingly it *will* update the `Experience` objects, but at the same time the PUT / PATCH (?) operation is actually replacing (not merging) the value of `$user->experiences` with the array you provide - that's why you loose the other relations.

You can achieve what you want in different ways though. You can either

- create a custom operation (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/controllers/#creating-custom-operations-and-controllers)
- use a DTO along with a respective input transformer (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/dto/#using-data-transfer-objects-dtos)
- (what I would do:) care for updating (instead of replacing) $user->entities in a custom (de-)serializer (https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#decorating-a-serializer-and-adding-extra-data).

**In any case you will have to manually take care for merging the existing `$user->experiences` with the ones provided by your PUT / PATCH request.**

*Edit:* Oh, of course there is another way, probably the one "recommended" by api platform: Just send a PUT / PATCH request for every `Experience`resource.